# Firing an event across 2 controllers AngularJS with two-way binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, binding, angular-directive

This is a question about Angular 1, not Angular 2.

My setup is somewhat complex: I have a controller (controller A) responsible for a specific page. On this page, I have a custom directive that takes input drawn from the controller on the page. This custom directive, however, also has its own controller (controller B), that I pass information into via bindings on the attribute. Much of the information I pass into this directive and into controller B is generated by and handled via controller A.

Controller A can essentially be described as controller B's parent.

However, the bindings into this directive with controller B are two-way bindings (`=`), so information changed in controller B in the directive should bubble back up and into controller A, due to the two-way binding, and because the initial attributes passed in are bound pieces of information for controller A.

While complex, this works about 99% of the time for me. I have a button on the page that I want to disable in this way: `ng-disabled=CtrlA.buttonDisabled()`.

`buttonDisabled()` is a function on controller A that takes information from the two-way bounded values in the directive to controller B in order to return true, disable the button, or false, do not disable the button.

In one specific instance, even when changing the values on controller B that should impact this function, the function itself does not fire, so my button is enabled when it should be disabled.

I want to know how to force `buttonDisabled()` on controller A to execute from changing values inside of controller B. Is this possible? Can I do this via $watch? If so, which controller(s) should I place this information?

Here's a very simplified version of my code:

Controller A:

```
$scope.userName = "";
$scope.buttonDisabled = function() {
    if($scope.userName){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Controller B:

```
$scope.userName = "";
$scope.clearUserName = function(){
    $scope.userName = "";
    //I want to call disableButton from controller A here
}
```

HTML for the main page:

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlA">
    <specialDirective username="{{userName}}"></specialDirective>
    <button ng-disabled="buttonDisabled()" ></button>
</div>
```

HTML for specialDirective template

```
    <input ng-model="userName" />
    <button ng-click="clearUserName()" ></button>
```

Directive setup:

```
app.component("specialDirective",{
    controller: CtrlB,
    bindings: {
        userName: "="
    },
    template: "directiveTemplate.html"
});
```

`userName` is two-way bound in specialDirective.

I can't move `clearUserName()` or `buttonDisabled()` into the other controller directly, due to other requirements.

EDIT: Thank you to the commenters who pointed out my flaws--I've done my best to correct them in this and my answer post. I wrote this example from scratch since it would have been too complicated to copy-paste my exact code, which doesn't use the $scope object directly, etc, so I apologize for my incorrect syntax. Please correct me if I missed anything else. (:

Comment: It is not wise to use the `ng-controller` directive in the template of a directive because the `ng-controller` adds a child scope. Instread use the `controller` property of the Directive Definition Object. For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api).

Comment: The code mixes double curly bracket, `{{ }}`, interpolation with Angular Expressions. This is not wise and asking for problems. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)

Comment: It is best to avoid two-way, `=`, binding. Instead, inputs should be using `<` and `@ ` bindings and outputs are realized with `&` bindings. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: With `<button>` elements,  both the starting and ending tag are mandatory. For more information, see [MDN HTML Reference - `<button>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Answer (score -1):

With some searching and now seeing Georgeawg's comment, I was able to figure out how to do what I wanted with using one-way callback binding.

By using `<`, I was able to bind to a callback function that I could call from Controller B that would send the message back up to Controller A. In my case, I was able to set `setDisabled()` as my function that would execute during callback. This is better than using $watch, because $watch is a big resource drain.

See the Catching Output section of this blog post as an example of what I did: http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/dissecting-bindings-in-angularjs/

Controller A:

```
$scope.userName = "";
var buttonDisabled = function() {
    if($scope.userName){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Controller B:

```
$scope.userName = "";
$scope.clearUserName = function(){
    $scope.userName = "";
    $scope.out(); //calling the callback the directive was bound to, ultimately calling buttonDisabled() from Controller A
}
```

HTML for the main page:

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlA">
    <specialDirective username="{{userName}}" out="buttonDisabled()"></specialDirective>
    <button ng-disabled="buttonDisabled()"></button>
</div>
```

HTML template for the directive:

```
<input ng-model="userName" />
<button ng-click="clearUserName()"></button>
```

Directive set up:

```
app.component("specialDirective",{
    controller: CtrlB,
    bindings: { 
        out: "<",
        userName: "="
    },
    template: "directiveTemplate.html"
});
```